# How to implement managed package interface?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, aura

I have installed a `manage package` in my sales force org. Package has given an interface to override/add custom business logic. It was working great with the below code.

```
global with sharing class MyDataProvider implements nameSpace.iDataProvider {
global String getData(){
        string query = 'SELECT Name,StageName,Account.Name,Amount FROM opportunity';
        List<Object> data = Database.query(query);
        return JSON.serialize(data);
    }
}
```

Now it has stopped working. It is showing error

> MyDataProvider is not valid.

Is something changed in new salesforce release(s)?

Comment: I believe there is a critical update on this part in February. I will search...

Comment: @m Peixoto can u please share it/